# vectors question on linear combinations

Tags: linear-algebra

If **v** **u** and **w** are three 3-dimensional vectors in the same quadrant but not all in the same plane, then what is the picture of all combinations c**u**+d**v**+e**w** with $c>0$ $d>0$ $e>0$ and $c+d+e<1$.

I got this to be two pyramids placed with their bases together and the tip being the point with vector **u**+**v**+**w**. However the book says that the picture is a pyramid so have i done something wrong here, thanks.

Comment: inside of a pyramid with vertices $\mathbf {0, u,v,w}$

Comment: ah yeah thank you

Comment: it should be noted this is not a vector subspace -- not closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the inside of a pyramid with vertices $\mathbb {0,u,v,w}$.

Points near $1\mathbf u + 1\mathbf v + 1\mathbf w$ are not included because $1+1+1=3\not<1$.